# How to simulate curl -X Post with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I was wondering how to simulate a `curl` command in `PHP`. I want to simulate this:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/token\?\
client_id\=your_client_id\&\
client_secret\=your_client_secret\&\
grant_type\=client_credentials\&\
scope\=public
```

I tried this:

```
 curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST,array(
 'client_id=my_id',
 'client_secret/=my_secred',
 'grant_type/=client_credentials', 
 'scope/=public'
     ));
```

But I didn't have any luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: A basic google search gives you the answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`http_build_query`](https://php.net/http_build_query) to encode your data to a query string, and then set the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option, along with `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_URL` params, and finally send it.

```
$s = curl_init();
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/token');
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    'client_id' => 'my_id',
    'client_secret' => 'my_secred',
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 
    'scope' => 'public'
]));
curl_exec($s);
curl_close($s);
```